Preview Version 5.0 interactive window hangs in Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) (Python)

I am running the Python Development Workload on Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.11.0 Preview 5.0.

I am following the Python in Visual Studio tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-03-interactive-repl?view=vs-2022

I have installed the ipython and ipykernel packages


When I open the Interactive window and enter $help it returns the keyboard shortcuts and REPL commands – OK.
However, when I enter an instruction like 2+2 – it hangs.
This is similar to the 2 year old Stackoverflow question IPython İnteractive Window in Visual Studio which I have also tried to use without success.
The problem appears a well-known one, see also https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1346983/python-visual-studio-hangs  Unfortunately their suggestions do not solve my problem.
PS.  Thanks to the person that cleaned up my formatting.
What am I doing wrong?

Why are you using VS for python? I think both VSCode and PyCharm are better alternatives

Because I have used Visual Studio for about 5 years.

I don't want to turn your life upside down, but VSCode is very similar to VS, same hotkeys, but much more lightweight, and it's more than enough for python. I do think you should give that a try. Interactive windows are not my thing, but you don't actually need VS or VSCode for those, just start up a prompt, activate your python environment, and type "jupyter notebook". Then click on the link in the console output and open it in your browser

My problem is caused by using Python 3.12 (64-bit) or anaconda3 which at the time of writing are the current versions of these environments.  It seems that at this time the Visual Studio interactive window only works with Python 3.9 (64-bit) which I believe was superseded May 17, 2022, more than two years ago.
